# Why isn't my EC2 Instance online after reboot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip

I rebooted my Amazon EC2 Linux Instance today, though Amazon's AWS website.  Now if I go to my website Safari says it can't find the server, AWS says my IP has stayed the same.  What is wrong here?

My website is [jeffarries.com](http://www.jeffarries.com) and my IP is 54.213.219.247

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: webserver not set to load on boot?

Comment: @Mike How would figure that out? I'm new to this, sorry!

Comment: @mike Never mind, used `sudo service httpd start` and now it's working, do you want to post your comment as an answer??  Thanks sooooo much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should make httpd service to start automatically on system reboot to avoid such failures.

on Redhat/Fedora:

> chkconfig --add httpd

On Ubuntu/Debian:

> sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults

Comment: I'm using Linux.